# How do I render text containing html with j2html java to html lib

Tags: java, html, j2html

Been using [j2html](https://j2html.com/) to create html from Java, working well but I don't understand how to use when I want something like this

```
<p>The fox ran over the <b>Bridge</b> in the forest</p>
```

If I do

```
import static j2html.TagCreator.*;

    public class HtmlTest
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            System.out.println(p("The fox ran over the " + b(" the bridge") + "in the forest"));
         }

    }
```

I get

```
<p>The fox ran over the &lt;b&gt;the bridge&lt;/b&gt; in the forest</p>
```

i.e it treats bold as just text.

Note simply doing

```
import static j2html.TagCreator.*;

public class HtmlTest
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        System.out.println(p(b("the bridge")));
     }

}
```

does render properly giving

```
<p><b>the bridge</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I've never used j2html, but looking at the [example](https://j2html.com/examples.html), if I'm not wrong, I guess the syntax should be:</s>

```
p("The fox ran over the ", b(" the bridge"), "in the forest")
```

Sorry my company environment doesn't allow me to download Eclipse etc to test..
.

Update: Above was wrong. But I've found a way - although it is rather complex:

```
p("The fox ran over the ").with((DomContent)b("the bridge")).withText(" in the forest")
```

Output:

```
<p>The fox ran over the <b>the bridge</b> in the forest</p>
```

`(DomContent)` can be removed but I retained for clarify. I guess the logic is that if anything added as text would be escaped, so the only way to make it work is to add the `DomContent` or `ContainerTag` instead.

Update 2: "Better" way found!

```
p(new Text("The fox ran over the "), b("the bridge"), new Text(" in the forest"))
```

or with a "helper"

```
import static j2html.TagCreator.*;
import j2html.tags.Text;

public class Test {

    private static Text $(String str) {
        return new Text(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(p($("The fox ran over the "), b("the bridge"), $(" in the forest")));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<p>The fox ran over the <b>Bridge</b> in the forest</p>
```

can be written as

```
p(join("The fox ran over the", b("Bridge"), "in the forest")
```

Comment: Is join function provided by j2html, cannot find it ?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/tipsy/j2html/blob/f87f9d864716809da2f6e61d946e9c12259d8e67/src/main/java/j2html/TagCreator.java#L71-L81

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer because this was one of the first results that came up when I searched for "j2html insert html"; essentially I was looking to insert HTML text into a file I am building with j2html.  Turns out the `j2html.TagCreator#join` method can also join text without escaping it so the following:

```
System.out.println(html(body(join("<p>This is a test</p>"))).render());
System.out.println(html(body(join("<p>This is a test</p><p>Another Test</p>"))).renderFormatted());
System.out.println(html(body(p("This is a test"), p("Another Test"))).renderFormatted());
```

Outputs the following:

```
<html><body><p>This is a test</p></body></html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>This is a test</p><p>Another Test</p>
    </body>
</html>

<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            This is a test
        </p>
        <p>
            Another Test
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the `renderFormat` method doesn't render the joined HTML, neither a surprise or a big deal; just worth noting.  Hopefully this helps someone performing the same search I did.